# So high temperature ubuntu 22.04 with amd ryzen 7 4800h and rtx 3050

Tags: 22.04, temperature, amd-processor

My problem: The problem is that when I have only the desktop open, the temperature can reach 65+ degrees, it can also jump a lot (within 5-8 seconds 50, 45, 60, 50). In Windows there is no such problem, in Windows the temperature is a maximum of 53 (only the desktop is also open). Another example: when I open a youtube video on Ubuntu, the temperature can be 75 degrees at all, while on Windows it is a maximum of 60 (despite the fact that the fan RPM in Ubuntu is 3500 in performance mode) and in Windows RPM is 2300. I did not find any obvious solutions to this problem.

Probably change OS to kubuntu help?

Comment: What does `lshw -c display | grep driver` say? Also, did you already install lm-sensors: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install lm-sensors` and then run `sudo sensors-detect` to properly detect all your fans and sensors? You will probably need to reboot after it finishes.

Comment: Have you looked into any cpu frequency governors? There's a few Gnome Shell extensions. I think [this one](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1082/cpufreq/) seems to be the latest.  You can usually set the CPU governor to **powersave** to limit the CPU and get longer battery life. **Ondemand** is similar to **powersave** but allows it to clock up only when needed. **Schedutil** is supposed to offer better performance than ondemand but still allows it to clock down when not needed although I read somewhere it's not as great as it used to be on newer kernels but still seems to work fine.